# Fragment fails to get view model after app was killed in the background and is navigated back to again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I can reproduce this crash by using "no background processes" from developer options or simply killing app process in the background. The crash happens when I navigate back to the app.

This is the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@9a22257: Unmarshalling unknown type code 4456513 at offset 5188
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2755)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3043)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:257)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:934)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle$Companion.createHandle(SavedStateHandle.kt:381)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:70)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:103)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:90)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:114)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
    at com.megamod.mages.details.ui.overview.OverviewFragment$vm$2.invoke(OverviewFragment.kt:59)
    at com.megamod.mages.details.ui.overview.OverviewFragment$vm$2.invoke(OverviewFragment.kt:59)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.megamod.mages.details.ui.overview.OverviewFragment.getVm(OverviewFragment.kt:59)
    at com.megamod.mages.details.ui.overview.OverviewFragment.onCreate(OverviewFragment.kt:75)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3090)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:257)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2884)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:252)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:220)
    at com.megamod.core.ui.AppActivity.onCreate(AppActivity.kt:38)
    at com.megamod.mages.details.ui.MagesDetailsActivity.onCreate(MagesDetailsActivity.kt:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

How do I prevent or handle this?

I suspect that this crash appeared when we migrated to using Hilt because it appeared in that release's crashlytics.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OverviewFragment : AppFragment() {

    private val vm: OverviewViewModel by viewModels()
    ...
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class OverviewViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val schedulers: Schedulers,
    private val session: OptionalSession,
    private val apiClient: ApiClient
) : GandalfRoomViewModel() {
    ...
```

Please feel free to ask me to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Do you interact with SavedStateHandle anywhere in the view model/fragment - (add it to the code)?

Comment: No, I don't. I can't find any mention of SavedStateHandle or anything similar in the code.